# The option "Invite my Facebook friends" in the facebook connect module is a white screen

Tags: 7, social-network

I don't understand why when I put click in "Invite friends from FB" appears a white screen. I can't see any list of friends to invite.

Comment: White screen indicates a PHP fatal error usually. Check out [this](http://drupal.org/node/158043) & please post if there are errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  With a white screen I refer with this:  http://screencast.com/t/YbsAzYQx.  Thanks again.